# Test Class for Task Data

Tags: unit-test

Please help me out with Testclass for this trigger.

```
trigger Address_Details_On_Task on Task (before insert,before update) 
{
    list<Account> Account_opportunity_list;
    list<Opportunity> Opportunity_list;
    list<Account> Account_list;
    list<Lead> Lead_list;
    Id Whatid;
    string Whoid;

    string testText;

    if (HelperClass.firstRun) 
    {
      HelperClass.firstRun = false;
    }
     else 
     {
       System.debug('Already ran!');
        return;
     }


    for(Task t:trigger.new)
    {
       Whatid=t.whatid;
        Whoid=t.whoid;
        testText=t.description;
    }   

    Opportunity_list=[select accountid from opportunity where id=:Whatid];
    Account_list=[select phone,billingstate,billingcity,billingcountry,billingpostalcode,billingstreet from account where id=:Whatid];   
    Lead_list=[select phone,country,street,city,state,postalcode from lead where id=:Whoid];
      if(testText==null)
      {
           testText='blank';    
       }

   //Account
   If(!(testText.contains('***** Account Information *****')))
   {

    for(Account a:Account_list)
    { 

         for(Task t3:trigger.new)
         {
          string descr = t3.description == null ? '' : t3.description;
          t3.description=descr + ' \r\n'+ '***** Account Information *****' + ' \r\n'+ 'Phone : ' + a.phone + ' \r\n' +  a.billingstreet + ', ' +  a.billingcity + ', ' +  a.billingstate + ', ' +  a.billingpostalcode + ', ' +  a.billingcountry;         
         }

     }

       }  

    //Lead

   If(!(testText.contains('***** Lead Information *****')))
   {
    for(Lead l:Lead_list)
    { 

        for(Task t5:trigger.new)
        {
        string descr = t5.description == null ? '' : t5.description;
        t5.description=descr + ' \r\n'+ '***** Lead Information *****' + ' \r\n'+ 'Phone : ' + l.phone + ' \r\n' +  l.street + ', ' +  l.city + ', ' +  l.state + ', ' +  l.postalcode + ', ' +  l.country;         
        }       

    } 
   }

        //Opportunity

   If(!(testText.contains('**** Account Information ****')))
   {
    for(opportunity o: Opportunity_list)
    {    
     Account_opportunity_list=[select phone,billingstate,billingcity,billingcountry,billingpostalcode,billingstreet from account where id=:o.accountid];                                            
     if(o!=null)
     {
      for(Account a1:Account_opportunity_list)
      {

           for(Task t1:trigger.new) 
           {
             string descr1 = t1.description == null ? '' : t1.description;
             t1.description=descr1 + ' \r\n'+ '**** Account Information ****' + ' \r\n'+ 'Phone : ' + a1.phone + ' \r\n' +  a1.billingstreet + ', ' +  a1.billingcity + ', ' +  a1.billingstate + ', ' +  a1.billingpostalcode + ', ' +  a1.billingcountry;    
           }

       }         
      }        
     }
   }   
}
```

Below is the test class written by me that I need help with.

```
    @isTest
public class TestClass_Task { 
    public static testmethod void testinsert_testupdate(){
        Account Account_opportunity_list;
    list<Opportunity> Opportunity_list;
    list<Account> Account_list;
    list<Lead> Lead_list;
    list<Task> Task_list;
    Id Whatid;
    string Whoid;  
    string testText;
      if (HelperClass.firstRun) 
       {
         HelperClass.firstRun = false;
          }
     else 
     {
       System.debug('Already ran!');
        return;
     }
         Account a=new Account(name='Testdata',phone='8885856208',billingstate='California',billingcity='anah',billingcountry='United States',billingpostalcode='92801',billingstreet='ls');
          insert a;
           Lead l=new Lead(role__c='general dentist',Company='kavokerr',LeadSource='Marketing',status='open',Business_Unit__c='Instruments',phone='8978645100',country='United States',street='James street',city='texas',state='devar',postalcode='98568');      
            insert l;
          Task t=new Task(subject='test_test',description='Account info on Task',Whatid=a.Id,Whoid=l.Id,status='open',priority='normal');
          testText=t.description;
         insert t;
          Task_list=[Select Whatid,Whoid from Task];       
          Opportunity_list=[select Accountid from Opportunity where id=:t.Whatid];
        for(Opportunity O:Opportunity_list){
            Account_opportunity_list=[select phone,billingstate,billingcity,billingcountry,billingpostalcode,billingstreet from account where id=:O.accountid];
                  }
        Account ao=Account_opportunity_list;
          if(testText==null)
             {
               testText='blank';    
                }
                //Account
              If(!(testText.contains('***** Account Information *****')))
                  {
               Task t1=new Task(description='task account data');
                      String descr=t1.description==null ? '' : t1.description;
                      t1.description=descr + ' \r\n'+ '***** Account Information *****' + ' \r\n'+ 'Phone : ' + a.phone + ' \r\n' +  a.billingstreet + ', ' +  a.billingcity + ', ' +  a.billingstate + ', ' +  a.billingpostalcode + ', ' +  a.billingcountry;         
                        insert t1;
                      }

        //Lead
              If(!(testText.contains('***** Lead Information *****')))
                  {
               Task t2=new Task(description='task lead data');
                      String descr=t2.description==null ? '' : t2.description;
                      t2.description=descr + ' \r\n'+ '***** Lead Information *****' + ' \r\n'+ 'Phone : ' + l.phone + ' \r\n' +  l.street + ', ' +  l.city + ', ' +  l.state + ', ' +  l.postalcode + ', ' +  l.country;         
                        insert t2;
                      }
        //Opportunity

              If(!(testText.contains('***** Account Information *****')))
                  {
                      if(Opportunity_list!=null){
                        Task t3=new Task(description='task account data');
                      String descr=t3.description==null ? '' : t3.description;
                      t3.description=descr + ' \r\n'+ '***** Account Information *****' + ' \r\n'+ 'Phone : ' + ao.phone + ' \r\n' +  ao.billingstreet + ', ' +  ao.billingcity + ', ' +  ao.billingstate + ', ' +  ao.billingpostalcode + ', ' +  ao.billingcountry;         
                        insert t3;
                      }
                  }

}
}
```

Comment: Hi Deepak, welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer you'll find helpful. Posting requests to write code for you generally get closed.

Comment: Hi, actually i am new to test classes and i need help in that ..That is why i have asked a help on that testclass. i dont understand what is wrong with that question

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal Questions need to ask about a specific problem, not "write my code for me". If you're new to test classes, you should look at [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro)

Comment: @DanJones.. FYI i didn't mention anywhere 'write my code for me'. i have just asked for help in test classes being new in that.Please see the quote properly and then comment.

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal "Please help me out with Testclass for this trigger." without posting any code you've written implies "write it for me". If you really want help in understanding test classes, see the trailhead link. If you need help with a specific problem with your test class, include it in the question and explain what it's not covering and what you're trying to do.

Comment: @DanJones.. I have posted my testclass there the trigger is for updating accounts and leads data on its respective task for that i need the test class

Comment: Please can you look into the test class i have posted its coverage is 0% and i am getting an error something like this

Comment: System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject..

Comment: line 24.System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Answer (score 1):

From what I see in your code, you first need to create data to test with. That means creating a RunAs user, an Account, a lead, an Opportunity and a Task that are all related to each other. There are plenty of examples for doing that. I suggest besides going through the [Trailhead Module](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/modules) for Apex Testing, there's also the [Testing Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing.htm) Section of the Apex Developer Guide which will provide references for how to do this as well as the [Apex Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex_workbook.htm).

Additionally, if you use the search features of the forum in the upper RH portion of this page, you'll find lots of examples of the code you need. See the [help] for how to use the advanced search features to get exactly what you want.